# How can I get value from upper element in xml file in for loop in xsl-fo?

Tags: xml, xslt

Imagine I have an xml like this:

```
<years>
    <year yearValue="2011">
        <month monthValue="1" workTime="10">
        <month monthValue="2" workTime="90">
    </year>
    <year yearValue="2012">
        <month monthValue="2" workTime="90">
    </year>
</years>
```

So when I am looping in my XML file

```
<xsl:for-each select="activityExport/years">
    <xsl:for-each select="year">
        <xsl:for-each select="month">
            <xsl:value-of select="@workTime"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="@monthValue"/>
```

However I also want to show the yearValue just after @workTime.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value you specify in `select` attribute of the `xsl:value-of` tag is a XPath expression. Base on XPath syntax, this value is the address of some tag or attribute in source document that has to be written on output. You can use relative paths in XPath expressions of your innermost loop to access `yearValue` attribute of the parent tag; something like '../@yearValue'.

So I think something like the this could be your answer:

```
<xsl:for-each select="activityExport/years">
    <xsl:for-each select="year">
        <xsl:for-each select="month">
            <xsl:value-of select="@workTime"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="../@yearValue"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="@monthValue"/>
```